# py.test управление упавшим тестом

Tags: python, тестирование

Я хочу тянуть логи с сервера, если тест закончился не PASSED  поскажите как выглядит сигнатура функции или фикстуры которая будет вызываться после каждого теста и обладать информацией о его статусе.

стартую срипт через

```
py.test -s -vv -l --alluredir allure/ main.py
```

Comment: какой тест? какой сервер? какая рыба?

Comment: @AndrioSkur я добавил вам код, но мой вопрос общий, и боюсь пример вам не поможет.

Comment: я думаю что та прога, которая запускает тесты, и должна ходить по `ssh`(или чем-то таким), и выкачивать логи самостоятельно

Comment: @AndrioSkur как выкачать логи я понимаю, мне как-то понять, что их пока выкачивать

Comment: Как тесты закончились, так и выкачивайте.

Comment: @Эникейщик там летит очень много логов я хочу их скачать в тот момент, когда упал тест

Comment: Как становится известно, что тест упал?

Comment: @Эникейщик в консоль выводиться пасед или фалид

Comment: А как стартуете? Запускается, видимо, какой-то скрипт? Значит нужно смотреть на вывод этого скрипта (к примеру, присвоить его переменной) и если фалид, то стартовать скрипт, тянущий логи.

Comment: @Эникейщик py.test -s -vv -l --alluredir allure/ main.py

Comment: Как вариант: направляйте вывод не в консоль, а в файл. Потом читайте содержание файла и если фалид, то тяните логи.

Comment: @Эникейщик это поздно, пока закончатся все тесты пройдет много времении, из вариантов только запускать тесты самому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures) предлагается делать это с помощью хуков. Пример кода (должен быть в файле conftest.py):

```
import pytest
import os.path

@pytest.hookimpl(tryfirst=True, hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    # execute all other hooks to obtain the report object
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()

    # we only look at actual failing test calls, not setup/teardown
    if rep.when == "call" and rep.failed:
        mode = "a" if os.path.exists("failures") else "w"
        with open("failures", mode) as f:
            # let's also access a fixture for the fun of it
            if "tmpdir" in item.fixturenames:
                extra = " (%s)" % item.funcargs["tmpdir"]
            else:
                extra = ""

            f.write(rep.nodeid + extra + "\n")
```

https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures

Comment: это конечно более красивое решение

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо [Эникейщику](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA) за подсказку. Я сделал еще 1 обертку над исполнением скрипта и анализирую вывод тестов. Когда скрипт  выдает сообщение FAILED я выкачиваю логи.